# Link string to url and make it clickable

Tags: hyperlinks

In my LaTeX code I have strings like:

```
\arXivid{1602.00735}
```

that create, in the generated PDF file, a link to, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.00735.

I'd like to have the string `\arXivid{1602.00735}` clickable, like urls in `goto-address-mode`, opening the relative url in the browser.

How can I do it? Do I need to use a text-property?

I don't really need to fontify the string like `goto-address-mode` does.

Comment: Can we eliminate the PDF from the equation and just make the `\arXivid{1602.00735}` clickable?  Also, are you seeking to incorporate this behavior into the AUCTeX library such that the text-properties are automatically laid; e.g., as `font-lock` does its thing?

Comment: The PDF stuff is only the explanation of what the LaTeX code does. It doesn't matter. I just need the string to be clickable and pointing to the correct url.

Comment: Have a look at `org-set-font-lock-defaults` and see how the links are activated as part of `font-lock` ... You may wish to do something similar with the AUCTeX or other similar library that you are using to fontify the buffer text.  The answer to this question, however, is non-trivial (in my opinion) but nevertheless completely doable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to define clickable text is explained [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Clickable-Text.html).

- put an appropriate face, e.g. `link` and the text property `keymap` on the link text.
- bind the `follow-link` event in that keymap to a function, e.g. `arXivid-follow`, that transforms the text into a link
- the function gets an event that leads you to the click position where you can extract the id and transform it into a link
- follow the link with `browse-url`

As [lawlist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2287/lawlist) indicated in [his comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63074/link-string-to-url-and-make-it-clickable#comment99490_63074), you can let `font-lock` find and propertize the link text in the buffer.

The following code defines a minor mode `arXivid-mode` that adds the required keyword to `font-lock-keywords`.

```el
(defun arXivid-link-at-point (&optional point)
  "Return \\arXivid{ID} link at POINT or nil if there is none."
  (save-excursion
    (when point
      (goto-char point))
    (skip-chars-backward "^[:space:]\\\\")
    (and
     (eq (char-before) ?\\)
     (looking-at "arXivid{\\([0-9.]+\\)}")
     (concat "https://arxiv.org/abs/" (match-string 1)))))

(defun arXivid-follow (event)
  "Follow \\arXivid{ID} links."
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((window (posn-window (event-end event)))
        (pos (posn-point (event-end event)))
    link)
    (if (not (windowp window))
        (error "Something is very wrong..."))
    (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
      (goto-char pos)
      (let ((link (arXivid-link-at-point)))
    (when link
      (browse-url link))))))

(defvar arXivid-keymap
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [follow-link] #'arXivid-follow)
    map)
  "Keymap for \\arXivid{ID} links.")

(defvar arXivid-keywords
  '(("\\\\arXivid{\\([0-9.]+\\)}"
     (0 `(face
      link
      keymap
      ,arXivid-keymap)
    prepend)))
  "Additional font lock keywords for `arXivid-mode'.")

(define-minor-mode arXivid-mode
  "Minor mode making \\arXivid{ID} clickable."
  :lighter " arX"
  (if arXivid-mode
      (font-lock-add-keywords
       nil
       arXivid-keywords
       t)
    (font-lock-remove-keywords
     nil
     arXivid-keywords))
  (font-lock-flush)
  (font-lock-ensure))
```

Comment: It works. I'll try to add the follow link with a shortcut (C.c RET) feature, like in `goto-address-mode`, by myself. Thank you .

Comment: Is `event` in `arXivid-follow` a mouse click by default? Can I change it to allow follow-lin also by typing (C-c RET)?

Comment: Evaluating `(info "(elisp) Input Events")` should tell you all you need to know about events.

Comment: I tried: `(defvar arXivid-keymap
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [follow-link] #'arXivid-follow)
    (define-key map (kbd "C-c RET") #'arXivid-follow)
    map)
  "Keymap for \\arXivid{ID} links.")` but I get: `Wrong type argument: commandp, arXivid-follow`

Comment: Yes, that's a bug in @Tobias's code I think: it needs to be made `interactive`: just add `(interactive)` at the beginning of `arXivid-follow` and see whether that works.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for pointing out the bug. I have corrected it. Don't know how I could miss it from the man-page.

Comment: Another way to get this working is to (ab)use `bug-reference-mode`

Comment: When I exit arXivid-mode also the goto-address-mode fontification is supppressed. Should I add `font-lock-fontify-buffer` after `font-lock-ensure` in the define-minor-mode code?